# Not able to load input data for fasttext

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

my input.txt contains the following:

```
__label__SPAM buy our products
__label__HAM Please send me the last business forecast
__label__SPAM buy viagra
__label__HAM important meeting at 10:00AM
```

But after running the command:

```
./fasttext skipgram -input ~/PycharmProjects/Pcat/input.txt -output modelskipgram
```

I get output as :

```
Read 0M words
Number of words:  0
Number of labels: 2
Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:     339 lr:  0.000000 loss:  0.000000 ETA:   0h 0m
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you can use supervised skipgram as skipgram is itself an unsupervised model.Try this.

```
./fasttext supervised -input ~/PycharmProjects/Pcat/input.txt -output model
```

Comment: Thanks its working now!!.. but I was following this: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/word-representations-text-classification-using-fasttext-nlp-facebook/, so mine should have worked though

Comment: That command is mentioned in unsupervised learning and It would be working perfectly if you want to do unsupervised learning.